# How to prevent LazyVStack from doing a weird subview animation after transition on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Something I've been stuck for few days is having ScrollView that consists of header view portion and `LazyVStack` with variable amount of subviews. On press of a button I'd like to hide header and move `LazyVStack` to fill entire scrollview.
However after transition it sorta moves subviews top down in LazyVStack when I start scrolling.
As far as I understand it is caused by `LazyVStack` resizing it's frame but there's no way to prevent that as is UX requirement.

I've tried multiple different layouts, setting static heights on every view involved, disabling animations in LazyVStack subviews.

The code that causes malfunction is something like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isHeaderVisible: Bool = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack
        {
            Button("Toggle")
            {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 2)) {
                    isHeaderVisible.toggle()
                }
            }
            ScrollViewReader
            {
                proxy in
                ScrollView
                {
                    VStack(spacing: .zero)
                    {
                        if isHeaderVisible
                        {
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(.red)
                                .frame(height: 300)
                                .transition(.move(edge: .top))
                        }
                        LazyVStack(spacing: 4)
                        {
                            ForEach((0..<100), id: \.self)
                            {
                                i in
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(.black)
                                    .frame(height: 100)

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .background(.white)
    }
}
```

And the result is like this:
[Gif of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNwNx.gif)